# In RWBY vol.4 did team RNJR kidnap Qrow?

Tags: rwby

In the end of the video we see Qrow getting stung and he was first poisoned there, but the next morning he and the children wake up and the children see him leaning against a tree. Ruby noticed something was wrong.

That was the moment the poison was discovered, but still the children take him without his consent. Not that he was in a state to object if he wanted to,  but they carry him for a long distance at multiple points and he is practically held against his will.

There is no evidence he wanted to go anywhere, not to mention that it's not clear where they were taking him.

[Ruby and Jaune carry Qrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwmqV.jpg)

Comment: By that logic, you could say that ambulance drivers are kidnapping unconscious patients.

Answer (score 4):

### Not at all

Generally speaking, most people want to survive. **As such, they don't mind being  carried to safety and given medical treatment if they're mortally ill, and in fact generally *expect* it.** Now, this might change if the person has made it clear they *want* to die—but nothing like that happened here. Qrow hasn't expressed any desire to die, and in fact was poisoned while trying very hard *not* to die. It would be a little perverse to deny that obvious impulse by leaving him to die and continuing on.

Plus, it's not like he's unconscious the whole time, either. It's particularly notable that he has plenty of time to "heroically" tell them to leave him and save themselves, and doesn't, probably because he knows that their odds will be better in the future if he's alive, and that he's not greatly holding them back. If he had any objection, he'd have said it, instead congratulating them:

> Qrow: It's quiet. Good job, kiddo.

They're not just wandering about aimlessly, either: they're trying to get to Mistral (specifically to Haven, as you guessed), which Qrow had previously (i.e. after being injured, but before they knew about it) advised them to continue doing.

> Qrow: So, we're on our way to the headmaster. Haven't heard from him in a while, even before the attack. I'm hoping he has the answers.

Given that it's a kingdom, the odds are good that they'll have better treatment than team RNJR can manage on their own. Their detour to the destroyed village is fairly logical, too: if they can find some medicine for Qrow, and keep him alive until they get to Mistral, everyone wins.

To back this up, it's not as if Qrow shows any resentment that RNJR saved him, either. Quite the contrary:

> Qrow: Hey, aren't I normally the one saving you?

Comment: I'm still a bit confused, in one scene ,i might have to look it up, he went for walk and obviously came at some point yes but I assumed that was to check on them not because he planned on sticking around. Didn't he want to leave?

Comment: At least that was how it seemed.

Comment: @Lucy - He'd been following them for days or weeks to keep them safe. He wasn't about to just leave! And even if he had wanted to, the injury would have changed his plans.

Comment: @Lucy - He was just going on a walk! He said so himself. And again, he'd certainly have preferred sticking around to dying even he had been planning to go elsewhere. If a person IRL is going off to get groceries, has a heart attack, and is transported to the hospital, generally they're not angry that they weren't left to maybe wake up and get their groceries.

Comment: @Lucy - If you got poisoned and fell unconscious, personally, would you prefer that people take you to get medical help, or just kind of walk around you?

Answer (score 3):

A lot of YouTubers complain RWBY trivialized kidnapping here but really they're not kidnapping him. They wanted to get him a cure for the poison. Also Qrow may not have given verbal consent to take him at that time, but that's irrelevant for multiple reasons such as he already said he would go with them

> Qrow: So, we're on our way to the headmaster.

That line alone was consent as he said "We're" as we are which referred to him and team RNJR. However the injury did change some things but he still doesn't act like someone who was being kidnapped he actually seemed happy after they got to Mistral and he had been cured. Proven when he said to Ruby

> Qrow: Hey, aren't I normally the one saving you?

it was in a way a joke but also it was a serious statement about how he almost died. But they saved him and he was thankful. Plus that whole time as you said yourself he was not in a state to object had he told them at any point when they were carrying him "Put me down." or "Leave me.", that would've resulted in his death so they would be right to ignore him it's just that he never said either of those lines. At any point that we know of that is.

Comment: Edit buttons not working

Comment: I hate it when quote drops don't work!

Comment: Wait, "a *lot*" of people think this? Really? Did they think that they should just have left him to die and gone on their merry way?

Comment: The overwhelming majority of people don't want to die, and those who do can kill themselves later. It seems very strange to insist that the majority of unwilling, unconscious accident or crime victims die so that a few people can commit suicide more easily.

Comment: (I totally agree with this answer, I just wonder what kind of framework people are thinking in here).

Answer (score 2):

Kidnap definition

> verb
>   1. take someone away illegally by force, typically to obtain a ransom.
>   synonyms:   abduct, carry off, capture, seize, snatch, take hostage, nobel
>
> noun
>   1. the action of kidnapping someone.

Can you explain why you think Qrow was being held against his will? Qrow doesn't express any desire to go but he doesn't express any desire to be left there either so you want to get technical then it's hard to say but in case of not getting technical then NO, they're not kidnapping him. They were taking to get medical attention and to Haven.